# Need help dealing with a Chaotic Evil murder hobo fighter

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players, player-vs-player

Okay so the title kinda explains it but I'll give some backstory to this extremely edgy non-creative character.

So this character is a human who spent his younger life trapped in a shed by abusive parents until he killed them. During this time he became some sort of sadistic child that wanted REVENGE ON THE WORLD FOR WHAT IT DID TO HIM(every teenager ever).

After doing that he escapes with his family great sword and his only goal is to trick people into trusting them and then killing them. His backstory includes the slaughtering of 15 merchants in a caravan he was guarding but 2 got away. He had so far unsuccessfully try to murder a beggar by buying him clothes getting him a job then for weeks traveling with him teaching him to trade before he tried to stab him to death.

This is where my party meets him, he stabs the beggar turned merchant and rightfuly so the guy screams and runs towards us off in the distance. Realizing the guy didn't die(my friends kind of an idiot) he attempts again with his great sword but just barely doesn't kill him.

The guy makes it to us and this is when my character realizes that the guy attacking in the background is cutting his face and his own arm (in an attempt to lie to us about the guy attacking him) then he walks over and before he does anything I cast sleep on him(I'm a wizard) and he falls unconscious.

This is basically where he some how with dice convinces my character and all but one of the three other party members that he was high and didn't mean it(the DM says we think he's safe which is bs) and now we've been dealing with him constantly lying for no reason and out of game threatening to kill all of us because that's how this crummy character acts.

My friend who plays this character has a bad habit of constantly trying to derail things and get special favors from the DM and succeeds half the time which is infuriating. The dm is also my best friend and allows us to be more creative than usual which I like but it's also just enabling my said other friend to just kinda ruin the game. So far as a fighter he just mid game says demons visited him in his backstory so he worked out with the DM a pact with them. He's now a level 5 fighter with a second life so when he dies basically a firey explosion happens causing massive damage in a 25 foot radius and he gets full HP back which is the most rediculous thing the DM has let him do so far because he thinks it's "interesting".

Now he has basically the equivalent of 70+ HP which is just insane because the bosses we've been fighting usually only have 50-60.

I will be fair that the DM has allowed me to gather ingredients take them to the Augur(a patron of arcane and sight) and enchant brooms that levitate 5' off the ground and can go 60' per turn. The difference is that I took hours planning them out to be balanced but I see I didn't need to do that because the DM just gives second lives out willy nilly if you just ask for a demon to do it. He is also rewarding my friend more powers just for killing a certain amount of people which isn't helping this murder hobo situation at all.

I flat out just want to kill this character but in game our characters think he's "okay" for some dumb reason.

The party consists of me(lvl5 wizard), my girlfriend (lvl5 rogue), the DMs sister(lvl5 druid), my brother was playing a lvl5 monk but I don't know when he'll be back, then Mr. Murder cuz it's fun(lvl5 fighter).

In the world our dm let us have a free feat because we all agree it adds diversity to making a character more unique and naturally I abused this being I rolled amazing stats of: STR14 DEX14 CON14 INT18 WIS14 CHA6, well the charisma sucks but I don't need it anyways. So my character is purely a variant human battle mage with 80-90% combat spells and cantrips and having THREE FEATS I have magic initiate spell sniper and arcanist totalling up 8 cantrips extra spell and spell slot making my INT19 now.

I have the following cantrips: Firebolt, shocking grasp, Ray of frost, frost bite, dancing lights, pres, bonfire and mage hand.

Spells: magic missile, cure light wounds, burning hands, ice knife, invisibility, gentle repose, fly, burning rays, arcane lock, sleep, mage armor, detect magic.. I'm pretty sure I have more combat spells but I do not remember them currently as I am writing this at work on break.

Now I'm just sitting here wondering how I'm supposed to take down this fighter? He's a variant human as well with great weapon mastery/fighting style and toughness feat. His stats I believe are: STR18 DEX13 CON10 INT9 WIS10-9 CHAR16. He built this character for the sole purpose of lying and backstabbing. He is really cocky which has him in jail currently when he went straight to the OUR enemies base and attacked them (killing 4 guys) before being knocked unconscious. Yet he still managed to convince a guard to not only let him out but also go with him(then kill him).

I don't really know what to do without metagaming but this is just a really annoying situation and the DM is only now realizing how overpowered this character is. How can I defeat this guy? I also apologize for making an extremely long post but I have no way to vent my frustrations. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the querent clearly states that they have "no way to vent [their] frustrations", and this question reads very much like a conversational rant. Additionally, they seem to be asking for brainstorming on how to solve a problem.

Comment: Just to flesh out @L.S.Cooper's comment, "disguised rants" are despribed in our Help Center as one of the [types of question not to ask.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Related: [this answer to "Best way to kill a problematic fellow player character?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68690/32840)

Comment: Just to clarify, is the player threatening out of game to kill all the PC's? Or the players themselves? There is a large and disturbing difference there.

Comment: I recommend paring this down to the relevant facts, as written this is mostly a rant with maybe a question hidden at the end, but I'm not really sure what it is. Are you trying to kill the other character, are you trying to resolve the bad behavior from an interpersonal level, are you trying to get your DM to reign things back, or is the issue that the DM is telling you what your character thinks? They are all separate, distinct questions. Also, was a Session 0 ever done? What's the nature of this person to the rest of the group (i.e. we're a tight group and this +1 murder hobo).

Comment: @L.S.Cooper I think it qualify more as "unclear what you're asking" than "off-topic". We answered many questions about players out of idea to vent their frustration (usually talk about it/leave the game). But here, it seems to start as "How to deal with a My-Guy player" and ends up into "Tell me how to kill him" - the brainstorming part. In any case, I politely suggest, Corvax, that you revise your question to clearly define what you're asking, in the limits of this site rules.

Answer (score 6):

### I see three diplomatic solutions and three nuclear options

This player has 'my guy' syndrome, and he has a power-fantasy to play out. The GM has 'my world' syndrome*, and isn't caring about player agency. The fact that he gives you stuff in play isn't really relevant here.

((What is “my guy syndrome” and how do I handle it?))

It's not his job to distribute phat lootz, it's his job to make the game fun for everyone. He hasn't been successful at this from what you're saying, because he doesn't see the problem with either Murderhobo's behavior or his own trampling of player agency. Both of these are red flags.

There are three usual diplomatic tactics for dealing with a bad player:

1. Talk to the player and explain that he's ruining the fun of other players
2. Talk to the GM and explain that the other player's behavior is a problem, and that dictating what the PCs think or feel is damaging to player agency, which is key to a good game.
3. Talk to the other players and get a consensus, bringing the issue up to the GM and other player together.

From what you are saying, it sounds like neither this player nor this GM are likely to listen or fix anything, but it's good gamesmanship to at least try them.

In that case, other techniques may fix your problem:

1. Insist that the 'bad' player be removed.
2. Leave the game. No gaming is better than bad gaming.
3. Stage a coup. This means the players, minus the GM and bad player, schedule a new game among yourselves, invite better people
   to join you, and carry on from where you left off, having
   narratively 'dealt with' the murderhobo. One of you would take over
   the game as DM from where it left off. The old DM's notes and plans
   cease to be relevant at that point, make things up from there, and
   you just stop showing up to the original DM's game.

It may be hard to get the DM's sister to go along with abandoning her brother's game and basically stealing his campaign, but if he complains, just tell him he's ok with it and that it 'seems fine' to him.

Or you start something new without them. This is likely to cause some hurt feelings, but hey, they haven't been too concerned about your feelings and enjoyment either.

***My World Syndrome** is just the GM version of 'My Guy' syndrome. It's subtler, since saying 'That's what the NPC would do' is entirely valid for the GM, but at the core, it means that the GM is trampling on player agency in order to force something to happen or to not happen, especially if it would mean a change to the setting or plotline of the story. So a GM forcing characters to trust another one when they wouldn't on their own, and certain types of railroading would count. For an exaggerated and humorous example, see ["The Hero of Parnast"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbWwHKYPSjc)

Comment: Maybe a link to [What is “my guy syndrome” and how do I handle it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it) and a note on what "my world" syndrome is would be useful.

Comment: About the "coup solution" the same thing can be achieved by starting a new campaign, so no stealing would be involved.

Comment: True, but that means abandoning your characters and story. So why let the DM and other player ruin the best parts?

Answer (score 4):

## Speak to them out of character

Dealing with this has many different problems, including causing tension in your friendship group, but the big thing that comes to mind is that before you do something in character, try speaking with them out of character. If you tell him and the DM that you aren't enjoying the campaign due to this, then really they should come to a compromise in some way, especially if other players are having a similar experience.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful responses. I also see as others have pointed out that I shouldn't rant and I apologise. Again thank you to those who helped me regardless of me breaking possible forum rules. I hate to blame it on the fact that I'm new here but that is the reason. Also to answer no the player isn't threatening real murder.

Comment: @Corvax no worries, there's a little bit of a learning curve here and we all go through it. We hope to see more of you around!